# Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 171 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'

Tags: sql

I have this code which I'm getting this error message "Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 171 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'."  I'm new to SQL any help or segetaions will be greatly apprecated.

```
-- Import SUBAREA
DROP TABLE VISION_SUBAREA
SELECT *
INTO VISION_SUBAREA 
FROM OPENQUERY(TOMSQLVISION,'SELECT *' 
FROM [VISION_2020].[REAL_PROP].[SUBAREA]
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you intend:

```
SELECT *
INTO VISION_SUBAREA 
FROM OPENQUERY(TOMSQLVISION, 'SELECT * FROM [VISION_2020].[REAL_PROP].[SUBAREA]')
```